# Sending a large array, in chunks of smaller ones, in a server client program in Java

Tags: java, sockets

I am currently working on a project in Java, where I have a large array of 20 integers on a server, which I have to send it to the client in chunks of 5. I am able to send the first chunk only.

How can I send the chunks one after the other ??

Server code:

```
public class SocketServer {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private int port;
String in;

public SocketServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public Socket start() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Starting the server at port:" + port);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    //Listen for clients. Block till one connects

    System.out.println("Waiting...");
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    //A client has connected to this server. Send welcome message
    //sendWelcomeMessage(client /*y*/);
    return client;
}

public void sendWelcomeMessage(Socket client,int[]z) throws IOException {
    ObjectInputStream sI = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream sO = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());


    sO.writeObject(z);
    sI.close();
    sO.flush();
    sO.close();

}
}
```

Client Code:

```
public class SocketClient {
Scanner c = new Scanner(System.in);
private String hostname;
private int port;
Socket socketClient;

public SocketClient(String hostname, int port){
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to "+hostname+":"+port);
    socketClient = new Socket(hostname,port);
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
}

public int[] readResponse() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    int[] x = new int[5];
    ObjectOutputStream cO = new ObjectOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream cI = new ObjectInputStream(socketClient.getInputStream());

     cO.writeObject(x); 

     while(socketClient.isConnected()){
     x = (int[]) cI.readObject();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
}

    /*for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         System.out.println(x[i]);
    }*/
    cO.close();
    cI.close();
    return x;
}
}
```

Comment: You are reading only 5 int[] x = new int[5]; Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420342/java-tcp-send-and-receive-multiple-messages-between-client-server-side-on-same?rq=1

Comment: Send them all at once. If you do 5 separate sends on a TCP socket, it is going to end up most likely together anyway because of the nagle algorithm.